# $C(X)$ as finitely generated $C^*$-algebra

Tags: gn.general-topology, c-star-algebras

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space. Suppose that $C(X)$ (or $C_0(X)$) is a finitely generated $C^*$-algebra. What we can say about $X$ ? For example can we characterize its inductive dimension, axioms of countability etc. ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The maximal ideal space $\Delta$ of a finitely generated Banach algebra is homeomorphic to a compact subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$. On the other hand, evaluation at each point of $X$ is clearly a complex homomorphism of $C(X)$. We conclude that $X$ is homeomorphic to a subset of a compact subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Edit: actually, if $X$ is not compact $C(X)$ is not a Banach algebra at all (locally compact for $C_0(X)$). In locally compact case, as Nik Weaver showed in comments, $\Delta \cup \{0\}$ is compact in $\mathbb{C}^n$, so $\Delta$ is homeomorphic to a closed subset of some Euclidean space.

Also, Stone-Weierstrass theorem shows that all such $X$ satisfy the condition.

Comment: To tighten this up, assuming $X$ is locally compact the condition is that it should be homeomorphic to a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$. Its spectrum including $0$ is homeomorphic to a compact subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$, and after removing $0$ it has the form I stated.

Comment: In response to the edit, compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ if $C(X)$, closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ if $C_0(X)$.

Comment: (It is usual to acknowledge comments when editing a post.)

Comment: @NikWeaver But is that all such sets? What if $X$ is not locally compact?

Comment: Wait! In that case $C(X)$ will not be a Banach algebra at all!